# Group Json data based on a field after converting it from csv to json in react

Tags: json, reactjs, react-hooks, grouping

In my react app, I am converting a csv file to a JSON object so that I can show it in a table in the UI. But I want to group the JSON data based on a certain field, "IP Address". All the area should be clubbed to a "AreaList" field which is an array of original "area" field.

Here is my source code where I am parsing the csv to json:

```js
React.useEffect(() => {
        Papa.parse(csvFile, {
            download: true,
            header: true,
            skipEmptyLines: true,
            complete: data => {
                console.log(data.data);
            }
        });
    }, []);
```

Following is the console log output of the above code:

```
[
    {
        IP Address: "192.168.0.1:61000",
        area: "JA1_JA2", job: "test",
        flow: "PartsServe",
        Component: "1",
        …
    },
    {
        IP Address: "192.168.0.1:61000",
        area: "JA1_JA2",
        job:  "test1",
        flow: "PartsServe",
        Component: "1",
        …
    },
    {
        IP Address: "192.168.0.1:63000",
        area: "JA1_JA2",
        job:  "test",
        flow: "PartsServe",
        Component: "1",
        …
    },
    {
        IP Address: "192.168.0.1:63000",
        area: "JA1_JA3",
        job:  "test2",
        flow: "PartsServe",
        Component: "1",
        …
    }
]
```

I want to group the json based on IP Address field. The resultant json should look like this:

```
projects: [
    {
        IP Address: "192.168.0.1:61000",
        AreaList: [
            {
                area: "JA1_JA2",
                jobList: [
                    {job: "test", flow: "PartsServe", Component: "1"},
                    {job:  "test1", flow: "PartsServe", Component: "1"}
                ]
            },
        ]
    },
    {
        IP Address: "192.168.0.1:63000",
        AreaList: [
            {
                area: "JA1_JA2", 
                jobList: [
                    {job: "test", flow: "PartsServe", Component: "1"}, 
                    {job:  "test1", flow: "PartsServe", Component: "1"}
                ]
            },
            {
                area: "JA1_JA3",
                jobList: [
                    {job: "test", flow: "PartsServe", Component: "1"}, 
                    {job:  "test2", flow: "PartsServe", Component: "1"}
                ]
            },
        ]
    }
]
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I could form the logic for you. May not be the optimised way but I did it in hurry.

```js
const data = [
    {
        "IP Address": "192.168.0.1:61000",
        area: "JA1_JA2", job: "test",
        flow: "PartsServe",
        Component: "1",
    },
    {
        "IP Address": "192.168.0.1:61000",
        area: "JA1_JA2",
        job:  "test1",
        flow: "PartsServe",
        Component: "1",
    },
    {
        "IP Address": "192.168.0.1:63000",
        area: "JA1_JA2",
        job:  "test",
        flow: "PartsServe",
        Component: "1",
    },
    {
        "IP Address": "192.168.0.1:63000",
        area: "JA1_JA3",
        job:  "test2",
        flow: "PartsServe",
        Component: "1",
    }
];

const uniqueIPs = Array.from(new Set(data.map((item) => item["IP Address"])));

const areaList = uniqueIPs.map((ip) => {
    const currentIpData = data.filter((item) => item["IP Address"] === ip);
    const uniqueAreas = Array.from(new Set(currentIpData.map((item) => item.area)));
    return ({
        "IP Address": ip,
        AreaList: currentIpData.map((area) => {
            const currentJobData = currentIpData.filter((item) => item.area === area.area);
            const uniqueJobs = Array.from(new Set(currentJobData.map((item) => item.job)));

            return ({
                area: area.area,
                jobList: currentJobData.map((item) => ({
                    job: item.job,
                    flow: item.flow,
                    Component: item.Component
                }))
            })
        })
    })
})

console.log(areaList);
```

Comment: Glad that it helped. You can vote up as well if you liked my answer.